# Can I temporarily disable optimistic locking in Hibernate even if the entity has a @Version property?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have an issue where I get a `StaleStateException` because a certain delete of an entity is executed in 2 threads. This is because a thread started by a REST call is deleting the object and calls another service to clean some things up there, but this other service puts some data on a Kafka stream as a result. This Kafka stream is constantly being read from another thread and also results in the object being deleted. But depending who gets there first I can get this exception:

`Caused by: org.hibernate.StaleStateException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1; statement executed: HikariProxyPreparedStatement@821401258 wrapping delete from notification_setting where id='f47ef4b1-eb54-4d3a-a6f0-fc4518704288'::uuid and db_version=0`

Now in this particular case with the delete being done by a system action, I really don't care about the `StateStateException` and resulting `OptimisticLockingException`. Both actions just have to delete the object and I don't mind who gets to it first. But I don't want to remove the @Version property entirely from this entity. Can I temporarily disable the optimistic locking for a particular delete?

The code isn't too relevant but here it is. I already tried deleting by id but a `deleteAll` has the same issue.

```
eventLevelSubscriptions.forEach(
            eventLevelSubscription -> notificationEventLevelSubscriptionRepo.deleteById(eventLevelSubscription.getId()));
notificationSettings.forEach(notificationSetting -> notificationSettingRepo.deleteById(notificationSetting.getId()));
em.flush();

for (NotificationSettingKey notificationSettingKey : notificationSettingKeys) {
    kafkaWritingService.removeNotificationSetting(producer, notificationSettingKey);
}
```

Note the flush because we need to make sure this part succeeds before updating another stream on Kafka.

I tried simply try/catching the whole code because I don't even need to perform the deletes in the second thread as they're already done in the first thread, but then Hibernate seems to get in a corrupt state where an exception still is thrown in the end.

```
Exception in thread "Thread-6" org.springframework.transaction.UnexpectedRollbackException: Transaction silently rolled back because it has been marked as rollback-only
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:753)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:631)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:385)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:747)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:689)
...
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) (note: this is my kafka consumer thread)
```

Answer (score 1):

A) You cannot disable optimistic locking. Why are you using it at all? This exception *may* be an indicator that your logic is *inconsistent*. Check if your logic is really correct.

B) If after reviewing you still want to keep the logic as it is, it means you should treat this exception in such cases as a *correct* behavior (otherwise back to A and review/change the logic), which means you should *catch the exception*.

C) If your current code is running within a single transaction: Don't delete all entities within a single step, because some of them might have been deleted, the others have not. A solution can be following:

- Put call of `deleteById()` to a new method
- Set transaction propagation to *REQUIRES_NEW* for this method
- For transaction propagation to have effect put this method to a separate class
- In the `forEach()` call this method instead of calling the repository

D) Consider also a non object oriented approach: Use JPQL or SQL to delete entries. Advantage: There will be no exception if some entries have already been deleted earlier.

Comment: For your questions: the locking is useful for if a user would update the entity. However, these are A) both delete actions and B) caused by a system event.

I did try simply try/catching it before but then I got another Hibernate error. I updated that in my post.

Comment: Sorry I didn't notice your edit until now. So what would this resolve? It wouldn't automatically make things work I suppose? I would still have to catch the actual exception, only it wouldn't affect everything else?

Comment: This would resolve problems with trying to determine what elements in the failed transactions were delete and what need to be resubmitted to delete. Suppose both transactions contain 20 elements and one of them is present in both. One of transactions will fail. But then you will have to determine what 1 element of 20 was really deleted in another transaction and what 19 elements you have to resubmit to delete them. I think such logic can be pretty complex. How have you realized it so far?

Comment: ... But when you delete each element in a separate transaction you just don't care about other elements: You will catch exception and if it means the element was already deleted, you will just ignore this exception and continue. Pretty simple logic in my opinion.

Comment: The thing is that in this scenario I don't care about failed deletes. So actually there is nothing 'wrong' in the current code except that we see an ugly exception. Because both of the actions delete the objects (the former action deletes everything belonging to a project, and the latter deletes some objects attached to another object in the same project), I already know that all required objects are deleted anyway.

Comment: I wouldn't even mind not executing the second action at all in this scenario. That's also why I initially just put the whole thing in a try/catch but that somehow still led to the UnexpectedRollbackException I mentioned.

Comment: However, I can't figure out in the code at that point if those deletes are necessary or not, if you're familiar with Kafka tombstoning at all, I just know that something with a certain key has been deleted and because of that I need to perform additional deletes. But I don't know the cause of these deletes, if it was because of a project delete then all data is already cleaned up anyway and the second action isn't necessary.